# Killing an SD card by supplying 12 volts

Tags: sd

I want to design a self-destruction circuit to destroy an SD card as a data protection procedure.

Will supplying 12 volts to an SD card  destroy it to a level that it won't be accessible again? (Can't access stored data any more.)

More details : at university we have robots competition, we have made a robot depending on Raspberry, the Python files which administrate the robot are stored in the SD card, other teams failed in the setup of their robots while we finished it successfully.. the rules of the university to leave all robots at the workshop room, a guard is locking it at the end of the day, we found later the robot is not normal and like someone tried to access it (maybe someone from other teams bribed the guard to access our robot)...

We were looking for securing the python files by killing the SD card if someone tried to get the Raspberry case out of the robot.

(I mean by "killing", "destruction" a physical or non-physical destruction, whatever at least nobody can access the stored files).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124368/discussion-on-question-by-m-sayed-killing-an-sd-card-by-supplying-12-volts).

Comment: Just leave the robot without its SD card overnight.